# Calling setInterval from within function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a slider and i ran into problem. I'm practicing modular `js` and this code works fine for the first time, but `setInterval` won't repeat itself so the slides continue changing. How to make it work? Thanks in advance.

```
var currentSlide = 1;
var slider = {

    init: function(){
        this.cacheDom();
        this.setInt();
    },
    cacheDom: function(){
        this.$panel = $('.slider');
        this.$actPan = this.$panel.find('.panel.active');
    },
    setInt: function(){
        return setInterval(this.mainFunction(), 3000);
    },
    mainFunction: function(){
        this.$actPan.fadeOut(2000, this.showNextPanel());
        this.$panel.find('.tabs li:nth-child('+ currentSlide +')').find('img').attr('src', 'images/g4228.png');
    },
    showNextPanel: function(){
        this.$panel.find('#panel' + currentSlide).removeClass('active');
        this.revert();
    },
    revert: function(){
        currentSlide++;
        if(currentSlide === 4){currentSlide = 1;}
        this.$panel.find('.tabs li:nth-child('+ currentSlide +')').find('img').attr('src', 'images/g4228.png');
        this.$panel.find('#panel' + currentSlide).fadeIn(2000, this.adder());
        },
    adder: function(){
        this.$panel.find('#panel' + currentSlide).addClass('active');
        }
};

slider.init();
```

So, I'm thinking that only `setInt` and `init` functions needs changing.

Comment: It works the same both ways @NishanthMatha

Comment: I suggest to look into ``prototype`` and always ``return this`` so your functions are chainable.

Comment: What do you mean repeat? do you want to stop the interval in some way?

Comment: No, i don't want to stop it. It stops itself after one iteration and want it to always repeat @seahorsepip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
return setInterval(this.mainFunction(), 3000);
```

This is calling `this.mainFunction()` and passing the result to `setInterval`; `setInterval` needs to be passed a function to call on an interval. Replace that with this:

```
return setInterval(this.mainFunction.bind(this), 3000);
```

The `bind` is needed so that `this` is preserved when `setInterval` calls it.